# I'm using Oracle E-Business suite 12, how do we know IP address from which transaction has been done

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs

I'm using Oracle E-Business suite 12, here question is if user had changed invoice data or did some wrong receipts intentionally, how can we know from which terminal (IP address)  this transaction has been done. is there any way we can know such information?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend a lot on the current logging and auditing configured in the system as well as the load balancer / reverse proxy configuration.  Also - Forms and OAF/JSPs behave differently in terms of how IP addresses are collected.  Key questions:

- Does the end user IP address reach the OHS / Apache or is the load balancer / reverse proxy IP passed internally?
- Are the apache access logs retained?
- Was this the last change to the record (so you still have the who column information)?
- Is there any DB Auditing or other auditing of those tables?

Information on this subject is in the Guidelines for Auditing and Logging in the [Oracle E-Business Suite Security Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26401_01/doc.122/e22952/toc.htm)

Comment: Getting information like 192.168.0.25 - - [28/Aug/2019:15:00:00 +0300] "POST /forms/lservlet;JsessionIDForms=sbnXPR8sZ9n1Ncl9jTkJfM4-_SQijZF6WlC0nMbeN3yUkcaxcDGP!-1082417284 HTTP/1.1" 200 201 in text access log file. For current question it is not important who made changes but most important is from where those changes has been done because the interesting thing is the user/password was shared among people. No, DBA audit was not set.

Comment: I assume this is from the access log.  Are the IPs end user machines?  Or the load balancer?  In any case, it's going to be difficult to determine which request corresponded to a change - especially if that came in through Forms, it's a shared account, and if you don't have any auditing on that table.  You can try and match timestamps to the who column dates.